# Why won't my nested function call after the conditional?

Tags: python-2.7

Trying to call 'dialogue_b1_a()' using the input function within a function named dialogue_b1(). When I call dialogue_b1() normally, the prompt works, but after I type begin, it simply says that 'process executed with exit code 0', instead of calling the function I put if continue_b1 == begin. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
def dialogue_b1():
    begin = 0
    print("You identify as a male.")
    print("...")
    continue_b1 = input('Type "begin" to continue.')
    if continue_b1 == begin:
        dialogue_b1_a()
    return
```

Comment: Why did you put "begin = 0" at the top of the function? You are not using that variable anywhere, and had you left it away, your mistake would be much more apparent.

Comment: I had assumed that the problem did not lie with the data type of begin, but that begin had to be defined first, locally.

Comment: It would have worked if you had used `begin = "begin"` instead of `begin = 0`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 they are using `begin` when they type it at the `input()` prompt. Python 2 evaluates `input()` as an expression.

Comment: @Duncan I see, that explains it.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong here. Either you mistyped the code in your question, or you applied the wrong label 'Python 2.7'. When I copy the code you posted and type `begin` at the prompt it does indeed attempt to call `dialogue_b1_a()`.

Never use `input()` in Python 2.7, always use `raw_input()`.

When you type `begin` in response to the `input()` call, Python 2.7 evaluates what you type as an expression. That is why you needed the `begin=0` at the top of the function.

If on the other hand you ran this code under Python 3.x typing `begin` will simply return the string `"begin"` from the `input()` call and the condition will not match. In that case the condition could never match as Python 3 `input()` will always return a string.

Corrected code for Python 2.7:

```
def dialogue_b1():
    print("You identify as a male.")
    print("...")
    continue_b1 = raw_input('Type "begin" to continue.')
    if continue_b1 == "begin":
        dialogue_b1_a()
    return
```

or for Python 3:

```
def dialogue_b1():
    print("You identify as a male.")
    print("...")
    continue_b1 = input('Type "begin" to continue.')
    if continue_b1 == "begin":
        dialogue_b1_a()
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

So you only need to change `begin` into string:

```
def dialogue_b1():
    begin = 0
    print("You identify as a male.")
    print("...")
    continue_b1 = input('Type "begin" to continue.')
    if continue_b1 == 'begin':
        dialogue_b1_a()
    return
```